# What's the difference between closing as spam and flagging as spam?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, flags, spam

**Update:** The "spam" closing reason has [recently been removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27277/why-is-the-spam-close-reason-for-questions-missing-on-su/27301#27301).

Original post:

As far as I know, a user gets a 100 rep penalty when one of their posts is *flagged* as spam often enough. I just noticed that this does not happen when the question gets *closed* as spam.

I assume this difference in behaviour is intended, and thus it suggests there's supposed to be a difference between flagging as spam and voting to close as spam. So what should be done in what case?

When should I only vote to close as spam, and when should I also flag as spam (the third possibility, flagging but not closing, probably doesn't make sense)?

Comment: I can still see it on MSO/SO...

Comment: @Marc Gravell: I guess it'll be gone when Jeff hits the big pink "Deploy!" button the next time...

Comment: @balpha - all sites are showing the version number as 5091, but SO and MSO still have "spam" as a close reason, while SU doesn't

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I agree, it's sort of redundant now that we have flagging.

I am considering removing "spam" as a close reason, just to simplify the close list a bit.

Comment: @Jeff: I prefer to let the community have the option of closing as spam.  This leaves more power in the hands of the people, and often gets faster results than a moderator flag in extremely obvious cases.  The flag is still necessary for older posts that get under the radar, though.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: I thought "spam" flags are dealt with automatically, without need for moderator attention?

Comment: @balpha: You're right, I thought it was only for offensive flags, but 6 spam flags will result in an automatic deletion as well.  Disregard my prior comment, I need to read the FAQ again. :)

Answer (score 3):

Since not everybody can close the spam flag is needed.  The flag means to get the attention of a moderator, which they might not of seen the question yet or at all.

If you have enough rep to close a question that is spam, vote to close the question.

If nobody else is voting to close because of low views, etc. . . Then i would use the flag as a back up procedure to get attention to a moderator.

Comment: You're suggesting that both ways are pretty much the same. But the absence of rep penalty for posts that were closed as spam says different.

Comment: and spam in a closed question is still spam. the question is only closed, not deleted after all.