# Policy on posts that seem to exist only to promote a link?

Tags: support, specific-question, spam

What is SO's policy on questions like [this fresh one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180254/good-and-quite-cheap-php-developers-where-to-find)?

To me, it reeks like traffic / PR whoring, even though it might be a legit question.

What to do? Close? Remove the link? Leave as is?

**Edit:** The question already answered itself:

> closed as spam by Michael Todd, AdaTheDev, Chacha102, Andomar, mopoke 15 secs ago

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15634/whats-the-difference-between-closing-as-spam-and-flagging-as-spam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is what the `Close as Spam` Button is for.

Comment: `closed as spam`. Done.

Comment: Don't forget to flag as spam as well.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of motivation (and in this case, the motivations are not good), questions and answers that consist of **only a link** are equally frowned upon.

Answer (score 1):

7 Downvotes, Closed as Spam, and link edited out, all in less than 8 minutes.  Good job Stack Overflow Community, [you know it when you see it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37194/are-there-guidelines-on-what-to-flag-as-spam/37196#37196).

Comment: To be fair, the OP edited the link out himself after people objected to it.

Comment: The removal of the link is still an effect of community action.